# PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found

Tags: php

Mi aplicacion me manda el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or
> view not found: 1146 Table 'base 1.datos' doesn't exist in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php:15 Stack trace: #0
> C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php(15): PDO->query('SELECT * FROM D...')
>
> ## 1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line 15

La linea de codigo es:

```
$registros=$base->query("SELECT * FROM DATOS USUARIO")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Comment: Como se llama la tabla? por que pones datos y usuario? así parece una sintaxis incorrecta, que tratas de obtener de dicha tabla?

Comment: Además de eso por favor lee [ask], los títulos de las preguntas deben ser claros del problema que pasa y escribir **mi aplicación lanza error** no dice mucho

Comment: La tabla se llama "datos usuario", estoy intentando crear un crud, la linea de codigo es para devolver lo que esta registrado en dicha tabla .

Comment: el nombre de la tabla tiene espacios? en su nombre es decir esta así: `datos usuario`?

Comment: Gracias, ya solucione el error jajaja

Comment: los nombres de las tablas no deben llevar espacios entre su nombre